# Path Integral of Photon

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, path-integral, variational-principle

I am having issues recalling how to perform integration by parts for the path integral of the photon, namely the term, $$Z[J] = \int\mathcal{D}[A_\mu]\exp(i\int\mathcal{L}\:dx)$$ where $\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$. Now, I know to first expand $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ as $$F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\nu A^\mu - \partial_\nu A_\mu\partial^\mu A^\nu + \partial_\nu A_\mu\partial^\nu A^\mu.$$ Now, I don't know if it is a crisis of confidence, but I want to combine the first with the fourth term, and the inside terms since they are antisymmetric to get something as $\frac{1}{2}(-\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\nu A^\mu + \partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\mu A^\nu)$ and then from here perform integration by parts on both terms where the first terms gives a $A^\mu\partial_\mu\partial_\nu A^\nu$ and the second term gives a $A^\mu g_{\mu\nu}\partial^\alpha\partial_\alpha A^\nu$ plus two terms that can be set to zero on the boundary. With this, you perform the usual Gaussian integral, and so on.

What I really want to know is, is this process correct, or am I skipping crucial steps, or missing the mark completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to write the Lagrangian density in the form $\Phi{\cal D}\Phi$ where ${\cal D}$ is some differential operator. In your case the important thing to study is

$$F^2=F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=(\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu)F^{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu F^{\mu\nu}-\partial_\nu A_\mu F^{\mu\nu}$$

Now the indices are all contracted, hence dumb indices which can be relabelled at will. In the second term relabel $\mu\leftrightarrow \nu$ and use anti-symmetry of $F^{\mu\nu}$ to conclude

$$F^2=F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=2\partial_\mu A_\nu F^{\mu\nu}$$

Now a single integration by parts manipulation gives you $$F^2=-2A_\nu \partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}+2\partial_\mu (A_\nu F^{\mu\nu}).$$

Finally use this to evaluate the action. After integrating and discarding a boundary term you will identify the operator you need.

Comment: OH, I can't believe I forgot the fact that they are all dummy indices and if they are being summed over in the same manner you can just switch them... which is why I can combine the terms as I did above. Thanks for that, and yes, you can do the above, but if I want the gauge terms visible, I still have to expand the force term, which gets you to the correct answer, as does the way I put in the question, but the big thing is they are both correct. Thank you!

Comment: @Cassem02 no problem. Just one small comment: if you proceed in this way the differential operator you get will turn out to be non-invertible. To really solve the gaussian integral you actually need the inverse of such operator. In that case you need to employ the Faddeev-Popov procedure to enhance the action with a gauge-fixing term at the expense of introducing ghosts (which in QED and Lorenz gauge will turn out to decouple). If you follow the same procedure to write the enhanced Lagrangian in the form $\Phi{\cal D}\Phi$ the new operator will be invertible and everything will work.